# Materialize autocomplete data not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

Consider [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ts0lD.png).

As you can guys see , the autocomplete values does not show properly.
I have tried many things, like expand the width and the height or make the data values smaller but no success.
I took the code from the materialize site.
The HTML Code :

```
<div class="input-field col s6">
    <input placeholder="Paris" id="fromfield" type="text" class="autocomplete">
    <label for="fromfield">Departure</label>
</div>
```

The Javascript code :

```
var airportsinfolabels = {};
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    airportsinfolabels[t[i].airportCode + " [" + t[i].airportName+"]"] = null; //countryArray[i].flag or null
}
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: airportsinfolabels,
    limit: 1,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {
        // Callback function when value is autcompleted.
    },
});
```

Any idea what it could be?
See [this link](http://materializecss.com/forms.html) also.

Comment: are you sure the airportCodes in your data are correctly formatted? if so, please show the result of `console.log(airportsinfolabels)` if you place it after the loop.

Comment: @OmarEinea yes i did the correct format https://i.imgur.com/862rBFK.png but still and the materialize format : https://i.imgur.com/76LHB47.png

Comment: everything looks right, can you reproduce it in a fiddle?

Comment: @Dan Schnau what do you mean?